# Objective C - Proper way to Allocate and Remove View Controllers with ARC

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting, allocation

Lets say I have a popup.  When a button is tapped the popup has to be allocated and presented.  When the close button delegate is called it has to be closed and removed properly.  I don't think I am doing this correctly for some reason:

In .h file:

```
@interface MainViewControoler : UIViewController
{
PopupViewController*            popupView;     
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) PopupViewController* popupView;
@end
```

In .m file:

```
..
-(void)openButtonPressed
{
  if (!popupView)
  {  
    popupView = [[PopupViewController alloc] init];
    popupView.delegate = self;
  }
  [self.view addSubview:popupView.view];
  popupView.view.frame = self.view.frame;
}

..
-(void)closePopup
{
  [popupView.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I don't want the this to have any leaks where if the popup is opened and closed 1000 times, it would not crash....Is this the correct way?

Comment: You'll just need to set it to Nil after you remove it from super view and that's that :)

Comment: But up there, I am just removing the view controller's view from superview.  Not view controller it self.  Should u remove the view controller it self and then make it nil?

Comment: No that's not a problem, you just need to set `popupView` to `Nil` and the viewController is taken care of !, you can also run your code and check for leaks using Xcode's instruments !, raywenderlich.com has a nice tutorial on how to debug leaks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not generate leaks, as you are allocating the popover once. However, you do not need to create an instance variable manually, or to set the popover property to nil, ARC will take care of this, unless you want to also deallocate the popover before your VC is deallocated.

Just make sure you are not adding the popover view multiple times to the parent view (i.e. not calling `openButtonPressed` again before calling `closePopup`.

.h:

```
@interface MainViewControoler : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) PopupViewController *popupView;

@end
```

.m:

```
-(void)openButtonPressed
{
  if (!_popupView)
  {  
    _popupView = [[PopupViewController alloc] init];
    _popupView.delegate = self;
  }
  [self.view addSubview:_popupView.view];
  _popupView.view.frame = self.view.frame;
}

-(void)closePopup
{
  [_popupView.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: You still want to set to nil when done as this code will keep the controller in memory longer than required.

Comment: I think I mentioned that in the response.

Comment: What if popupView has a delegate? Should I make that nil too after?

Comment: Same concepts apply. Just define your delegate property as weak. ARC will take care of setting it to nil as soon as the delegated object is deallocated. ARC is cool :)